# Cannot use Toothpick.inject in Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, inject, toothpick-di

I'm getting strange error while trying to use Toothpick DI in a fragment:

> toothpick.registries.NoFactoryFoundException: No factory could be found for class android.app.Application. Check that the class has either a @Inject annotated constructor or contains @Inject annotated members. If using Registries, check that they are properly setup with annotation processor arguments.

My fragment:

```
public class ApplicationMenu extends SidebarFragment {

@Inject ApplicationsService applicationsService;
@Inject SectionsService sectionsService;

private EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toothpick.inject(this, Toothpick.openScope(LauncherActivity.class)); // <- Erroring here       
}

...

}
```

Activity:

```
public class LauncherActivity extends SidebarActivity {

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Scope scope = Toothpick.openScopes(LauncherApplication.class, LauncherActivity.class);
    scope.bindScopeAnnotation(LauncherActivitySingleton.class);
    scope.installModules(new LauncherActivityModule(this));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toothpick.inject(this, scope);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    ...
}

...

}
```

The strange thing is I get the error only in fragments, all injections in other places (ViewRenderers, Adapters, Services etc) work fine with no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that out. I close the application scope in one of my services by mistake. That service was using in fragments which cases the error.

Unfortunately the error message does not provide any useful information and the only way to find the problem is to analyze and debug all the code.

So using the toothpick di you have to be very careful with scope life-cycle.